# What was "cloak blink time"?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

An old item set for the Spy, the Saharan Spy, was added to Team Fortress 2.

The set bonus said:

```
Reduced decloak sound volume
0.5 sec longer cloak blink time
```

What does "cloak blink time" mean?   Is this the time that you are still visible while turning cloaked, or is it the time you appear when you get hit or bump into something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cloak blink time is the time the spy "shimmers" and becomes partially visible after getting hit or bumping into enemy players - your 2nd guess is accurate.

0.5 seconds may not sound like a particularly long duration, but I've personally killed a lot of spies because of that blink effect and I do believe this will have impact on gameplay. Usually when I attack a blinking spy I don't 100% know where he is, just the general direction he was walking in the last time I hit him. With this, I might be able to chain my shots while the spy remains visible the whole time.

Comment: Because of this, the Saharan Spy Set generally works better with the Dead Ringer, which only has blink time after the first 8 or so seconds (i.e. which you can only get if you grab additional ammo boxes).  The reduced decloak volume is also geared at the Dead Ringer.

Comment: @Powerlord I gave your comment +1, but the more I play with _The Sarahan Spy_ set, the more I feel like it works best with the Cloak and Dagger.  One side effect of using _Your Eternal Reward_ is that you can't disguise anymore (unless you backstab someone).  The reduced decloak noise works even better for "standard" cloak, since it's pretty quiet to begin with.  With the dead ringer, I usually have to let them "kill" me in order to get into position, which seems to always get them suspicious.

Comment: @TM: I tend to pull up the DR usually while backpeddling and shooting at them... or any time I see crits.